# how does docker-swarm expose port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

After I deploy a docker application using docker-swarm, the application is accessible from $mac-host-ip:8481, and then I noticed the following from my host (Mac),

```
$ sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN |grep 8481
dockerd   1882   root   97u  IPv6 287775      0t0  TCP *:8481 (LISTEN)

$ docker ps --filter publish=8481
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

$ docker ps --filter expose=8481
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

is this expected for compose applications?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ingress is used, the port gets published directly on the service, you'll see that under `docker service ls` under the ports column. The published port is forwarded to the VIP assigned to the service, which (at last check, it's been a while since I've dug) is then forwarded to one of the containers in the service using IPVS.

```sh
$ docker service create -p 8080:80 --name nginx-test nginx
mvwgqaolsjbiqsoo4d1ett20v
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks    
1/1: running   [==================================================>]                                                                                                                                               
verify: Service converged                  

$ docker service ls | grep nginx-test                                                                     
mvwgqaolsjbi        nginx-test                 replicated          1/1                 nginx:latest                                       *:8080->80/tcp
```

You can also go see published ports with a `service inspect`, e.g. the following loops through all services to show their ports:

```sh
docker service ls -q | while read service_id; do
  docker service inspect $service_id -f \
    '{{.Spec.Name}} - {{range .Spec.EndpointSpec.Ports}}{{.PublishedPort}} {{end}}'
done | sort
```

Comment: thank you, @BMitch!
yes, this is indeed implemented using docker service and I could see the mapping from 'docker service ls' output.